# C# LINQ Not able to update datatable value

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to find data in xml file using LINQ but my ANY() or WHERE clause found no data. what is the problem in my approach not clear.

I have a xml file which has been created by Dataset WriteXml() function. This way i am querying xml data by LINQ and data not found occur.

### See my XML structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<TER_ViewAll>
<dgvViewAll_Vertical>
    <Section_x0020_>ML</Section_x0020_>
    <LineItem>BofA Merrill Lynch</LineItem>
    <Revise_x0020_Date>01-16-2018</Revise_x0020_Date>
    <_x0032_010_x0020_FYA>1608.6500</_x0032_010_x0020_FYA>
    <_x0032_011_x0020_FYA>1429.0610</_x0032_011_x0020_FYA>
    <_x0032_012_x0020_FYA>1656.7500</_x0032_012_x0020_FYA>
    <_x0032_013_x0020_FYA>1427.9330</_x0032_013_x0020_FYA>
    <_x0031_Q_x0020_2014A>321.0100</_x0031_Q_x0020_2014A>
    <_x0032_Q_x0020_2014A>525.5670</_x0032_Q_x0020_2014A>
    <_x0033_Q_x0020_2014A>478.0100</_x0033_Q_x0020_2014A>
    <_x0034_Q_x0020_2014A>323.2360</_x0034_Q_x0020_2014A>
    <_x0032_014_x0020_FYA>1647.8230</_x0032_014_x0020_FYA>
    <_x0031_Q_x0020_2015A>342.4010</_x0031_Q_x0020_2015A>
    <_x0032_Q_x0020_2015A>512.7390</_x0032_Q_x0020_2015A>
    <_x0033_Q_x0020_2015A>465.9940</_x0033_Q_x0020_2015A>
    <_x0034_Q_x0020_2015A>318.4440</_x0034_Q_x0020_2015A>
    <_x0032_015_x0020_FYA>1639.5780</_x0032_015_x0020_FYA>
    <_x0031_Q_x0020_2016A>430.9940</_x0031_Q_x0020_2016A>
    <_x0032_Q_x0020_2016A>531.7920</_x0032_Q_x0020_2016A>
    <_x0033_Q_x0020_2016A>410.4750</_x0033_Q_x0020_2016A>
    <_x0034_Q_x0020_2016A>379.9890</_x0034_Q_x0020_2016A>
    <_x0032_016_x0020_FYA>1753.2500</_x0032_016_x0020_FYA>
    <_x0031_Q_x0020_2017A>456.9130</_x0031_Q_x0020_2017A>
    <_x0032_Q_x0020_2017A>696.9010</_x0032_Q_x0020_2017A>
    <_x0033_Q_x0020_2017A>503.3780</_x0033_Q_x0020_2017A>
    <_x0034_Q_x0020_2017A />
    <_x0032_017_x0020_FYA />
    <_x0031_Q_x0020_2018A />
    <_x0032_Q_x0020_2018A />
    <_x0033_Q_x0020_2018A />
    <_x0034_Q_x0020_2018A />
    <_x0032_018_x0020_FYA />
    <_x0031_Q_x0020_2019A />
    <_x0032_Q_x0020_2019A />
    <_x0033_Q_x0020_2019A />
    <_x0034_Q_x0020_2019A />
    <_x0032_019_x0020_FYA />
    <_x0031_Q_x0020_2020A />
    <_x0032_Q_x0020_2020A />
    <_x0033_Q_x0020_2020A />
    <_x0034_Q_x0020_2020A />
    <_x0032_020_x0020_FYA />
    <_x0031_Q_x0020_2021E />
    <_x0032_Q_x0020_2021E />
    <_x0033_Q_x0020_2021E />
    <_x0034_Q_x0020_2021E />
    <_x0032_021_x0020_FYE />
    <_x0031_Q_x0020_2022E />
    <_x0032_Q_x0020_2022E />
    <_x0033_Q_x0020_2022E />
    <_x0034_Q_x0020_2022E />
    <_x0032_022_x0020_FYE />
    <GroupKey>Consensus Model~Net Revenue~TRIN~NBM~~1~ML</GroupKey>
  </dgvViewAll_Vertical>
  </TER_ViewAll>
```

the above xml is one records sample and my xml file has many records like above one.
i load that xml file by DataSet and querying by LINQ. this way i am querying.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string QCViewPath_savepath = @"C:\Test.xml";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(QCViewPath_savepath);

        if (ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Any(a => a.Field<string>("Section ") == "ML"
                        && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Contains("Consensus Model")
                        && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Contains("Net Revenue")
                        && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Contains("NBM")
                        && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Contains("1")
                        && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Contains("ML")
                        ))
        {
            //ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(a => a.Field<string>("Section ") == "ML"
            //     && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[0].Trim() == "Consensus Model"
            //     && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[1].Trim() == "Net Revenue"
            //     && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[3].Trim() == "NBM"
            //     && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[4].Trim() == "1"
            //     && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[5].Trim() == "ML"
            //     ).ToList<DataRow>()
            //     .ForEach(r =>
            //     {
            //         r["2010 FYA"] = 1200;
            //     });

            var rowsToUpdat = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(a => /*a.Field<string>("Section ") == "ML"
                 &&*/ a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[0].Trim() == "Consensus Model"
                 && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[1].Trim() == "Net Revenue"
                 && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[3].Trim() == "NBM"
                 && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[4].Trim() == "1"
                 && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[5].Trim() == "ML"
                 );

            foreach (var row in rowsToUpdat)
            {
                row.SetField("2010 FYA", "1200");
                //row.SetField("enddate", enDate);
            }
        }
    }
```

My object is to update data table periodical value and save that data at last after all update. after query by LINQ i am getting this message when inspect **rowsToUpdat** **Enumeration yielded no results** please help with rectified code. Thanks

Comment: Should that a GroupKey contain all those values at the same time, or did you mean an OR combination?

Comment: each records will have different combination. there was little bug in code and now fixed and shared here. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes issue fixed. sharing working code.

```
    string QCViewPath_savepath = @"C:\Test.xml";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(QCViewPath_savepath);

    if (ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Any(a => a.Field<string>("Section ") == "ML"
             && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[0].Trim() == "Consensus Model"
             && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[1].Trim() == "Net Revenue"
             && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[3].Trim() == "NBM"
             && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[5].Trim() == "1"
             && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[6].Trim() == "ML"
                    ))
    {

        ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(a => a.Field<string>("Section ") == "ML"
             && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[0].Trim() == "Consensus Model"
             && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[1].Trim() == "Net Revenue"
             && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[3].Trim() == "NBM"
             && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[5].Trim() == "1"
             && a.Field<string>("GroupKey").Split('~')[6].Trim() == "ML"
             ).ToList<DataRow>()
             .ForEach(r =>
             {
                 r["2010 FYA"] = 1200;
             });

        //foreach (var row in rowsToUpdat)
        //{
        //    row.SetField("2010 FYA", "1200");
        //}
    }
```